# Where should I do the core logic code in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.js for my website. I have created the directory structure using 'express-generator'. It contains 'views' folder to render views. It also has 'routes' folder for routing purpose. Now my question is where should I define or do the core logic code?

Comment: For a web server, isn't the "core logic" in the code that processes routes?  Isn't that what a web server does?  You can, of course, create your own modules for code that you wish to share within your other application files. Beyond that, you'll have to say what your "core logic" is before we have any idea where it should go or how it should be structured.

Comment: You could have a core folder with each module seperated into files. Shameless plug, https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap

Comment: what do you define as "core logic"?

Comment: You probably mean your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

For organization purposes, I use `/controllers` for my, well, controllers (which I believe is what you mean). Express really doesn't care where you put your code, just as long as you correctly use `require('./path/to/whatever/directoryname/you/choose/filename')` in your routes and views and `module.exports = controllerToExpose;` in your controllers.